# Does inverse image of idempotent element contain an idempotent element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, idempotents

Suppose $f\colon \oplus A_i\to\oplus B_j$ is a ring homomorphism, where $A_i,B_j$ are local rings. Both sides have finitely many summands. Suppose an idempotent $x$ (i.e. $x=x^2$) is in the image of $f$. Can we always choose an idempotent in $f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that the second ring is disjoint from the first. When you say an element is an idempotent element and it is an image of f, it just means that it is either an idempotent element of the first ring or it is an idempotent element of the second ring. Also, it's easy to show that in any ring, any idempotent element of that ring other than 1 doesn't have a multiplicative inverse. That might have been why this question was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, we want to lift the idempotents from $(\oplus_{i=1}^nA_i)/I$, where $I$ is an ideal of $\oplus_{i=1}^nA_i$, to $\oplus_{i=1}^nA_i$. Since $I=\oplus_{i=1}^nI_i$ with $I_i\subset A_i$ ideals, the question reduces to the following

> Let $A$ be a local ring. Then the idempotents lift modulo any ideal $J\subset A$.

If $a+J$ is idempotent, then since $A/J$ is also local we get $a\in J$ or $1-a\in J$.

Answer (score -1):

Since $B_i $ are local, so the set of idempotents of $B_i $ has only 0 and 1. Thus $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...) $ where $x_i $are 0 or 1 and almost all of them are 0. So $x$ has an idempotents preimage.

Comment: Does your argument hold for $i_1: R\to R\oplus R$? How did you modify a preimage $c$ of $x$ to an idem potent?

Comment: "The units of the right hand side are these elements, and we are done" is not very convincing. How did you account for f?